# Display JSON object in template angular 2

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have this:

```
stanservice.categoryDetail(this.params.get('id'))
  .then((data) => {
    this.category = JSON.stringify(data.res.rows[0]);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data.res.rows[0]));
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error message", error.err);
  });
```

The console log returns this:

```
{"id":6,"name":"destiny","note":"nice","type":"income"}
```

Then I am able to display `this.category` in my template as this:

```
{{ category }}
```

which returns this

```
{"id":6,"name":"destiny","note":"nice","type":"income"}
```

However, when I try to display the values of the object by doing this

```
{{ category.name }}
```

I get this error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in [
            {{ category.name }}
         in CategorydetailPage@16:18]
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_CategorydetailPage_0.detectChangesInRecordsInternal (viewFactory_CategorydetailPage:67:28)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.detectChangesInRecords (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:13535:18)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:13512:14)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesInViewChildren (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:13612:18)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:13516:14)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.detectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:13501:73)
    at ChangeDetectorRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:14402:73)
    at ViewController.willEnter (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:46071:22)
    at NavController._postRender (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:44385:30)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:44333:27
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `this` keyword within the `then` function. And don't stringify your JavaScript object. Instead of:

```
stanservice.categoryDetail(this.params.get('id'))
   .then((data) => {
       this.category = JSON.stringify(data.res.rows[0]);
       console.log(JSON.stringify(data.res.rows[0]));
})
.catch((error) => {
   console.log("Error message", error.err);
});
```

Try:

```
var app = this;

stanservice.categoryDetail(this.params.get('id'))
   .then((data) => {
      app.category = data.res.rows[0];
      console.log(data.res.rows[0]);
})
.catch((error) => {
   console.log("Error message", error.err);
});
```

Comment: Same error above `Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in [
            {{ category.name }}`

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(data.res.rows[0])` instead of `console.log(JSON.stringify(data.res.rows[0]))`? Do you see an object or a string in the console? An object will let you interact with it. A string won't.

Comment: `Object {id: 3, name: "ok", note: "notes", type: "expense"}`

Comment: @Rexford Could you try my amended answer?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did this and happens to work: `this.category = data.res.rows[0];`, then did this in template `{{ category?.name }}`

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that you can assign to `this.category` within the `then` function. `this` should evaluate to `window`, hence the need to assign `this` to a variable outside the callback function first.

Comment: If you `console.log(this)` within the `then` function, do you get an object referencing the app or the window?

Comment: doing console.log in the `then` returns: `CategorydetailPage {nav: Nav, params: NavParams, category: Object}`

Comment: I see. Thx for that. I've not used angular 2 as yet. In angularjs it returns `window`. They must be using `call` or `apply` when calling the callback. Makes for easier coding I suppose.

Comment: On android though, the ngFor items don't show. They show on PC, but not in android app.